# JAWS does not read ul and li elements as a list

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

NVDA reads correctly. JAWS read only Link 1, Link 2 (content is Link 1, Link 2), but do not read that is is a list

```
list-style-type: none;
```

html:

```
<ul role="list" class="content-links">
        <sly data-sly-list.link="${model.links}">
            <li role="listitem">
                <a href="${link.href @ context='html'}" aria-label="${link.label}" rel="${link.rel}"
                   tms-dblclick="${link.tracking.tmsDblClick}" data-pid="${link.tracking.vadm.pin}" data-pid-action="${link.track.vadm.pinAction}">
                    ${link.label}
                </a>
            </li>
        </sly>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why are you adding roles on the native elements?

Comment: Because native elements where ignored in this case so I add roles as a test. Just to check if this will work. Without roles NVDA read this code correctly (list, X elements). Jaws doesn't. Only as separate elements.

Comment: The roles will do more harm than good and should be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is correct (other than the superfluous roles you have specified, as pointed out by @shannon).  Unfortunately, that's just how JAWS works.  When you <kbd>tab</kbd> to a link that is contained in a list, the link text is read and the fact that the link is contained in a list is **not** read.  But if you navigate the DOM using the up/down arrow keys in JAWS, when you navigate to the link, you **will** hear "list of 3 items" before you hear the link text.  And you'll hear "list end" when you arrow down past the list.  Native JAWS users are used to it (not that that makes it the right user experience.)

Comment: Good answer.  I think perhaps many developers don't realize that different screen readers have their own design philosophy for how and/or when various document semantics are announced.

Answer (score 1):

The link text should provide enough information by itself for a user to know what will happen if the link is clicked. JAWS users can find out that the link is part of a list if it's relevant. Don't worry that JAWS doesn't mention that it's in a list as the user tabs through, as this isn't expected behaviour.